# How do you find out the tasks and task names available with Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

If I want to install a program using its .exe file via the command line, then I know I can change the options from the default using the `/TASKS` switch, but how do I find out what tasks are available and what their respective task names are?

I know I can run the setup and use the `/SAVEINF` switch to save the settings used to a file. At the bottom of the file is a `Tasks=` section which lists task names for the settings used. This is limited in how useful it is as the task names are displayed without descriptions and it's not always easy to make a good guess as to what a task name does, and the task names displayed are for the default options that were actually used in that setup, not the options that are unchecked by default but which I would have wanted to use had I known about them. It also requires that I actually go through the setup process, and then uninstall it and start the setup again to use different options.

Edit: I also tried unpacking the .exe file using [Innounp](http://innounp.sourceforge.net/) and I did find information related to task names in the `install_script.iss` file. Alternative suggestions are welcome though.

Comment: I assume that this installer is not your own then? Is it not possible to ask the authors of the setup for this information? If indeed there is a test case for it? Surely it is their responsibility to detail any command line useage of their setup if they expect it to be used in such a way?

Comment: I do not think, there's any built-in solution for listing the tasks. So I believe your use of Innounp is the best option available.