# TASK Names for Visual Studio Code for Windows System Installer script in Powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Looking for some help on writing a PowerShell script to install Visual Studio Code.
I have downloaded the Windows 64 System installer: VSCodeSetup-x64-1.56.2

My script so far:

```
$fullPath = <<Installer location>>
$vscApp = "VSCodeSetup-x64-1.56.2"
$appPath = join-path $fullPath $vscApp
Write-Host "App Path" $appPath
$arguments = '/SILENT /ALLUSERS /mergetasks="!runcode,????, ????, ???? ,????"'
Start-Process $appPath $arguments -Verb RunAs -Wait
```

I need the list of internal names for all of the check box items on the "Select Additional Tasks"
[Select Additional Tasks GUI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryNwW.png)

I want to turn on all four other tasks, both Add Open, Register code, and Add to Path.  Only 1 of which seems to be default.  While I do not need the desktop icon, from the Inno Setup docs, https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline, I can see the desktop Icon name is `desktopicon`. How and where would I find this list?

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Following this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410865/how-do-you-find-out-the-tasks-and-task-names-available-with-inno-setup 
I am trying these two options: 1 the /SAVEINF  to get a file with them listed.

Comment: After adding the `/SAVEINF="vscInstallLog" ` to my arguments list.  and then doing a file search for the file which was located in C:\Windows\SysWOW64
I was able to open the file and find my list of tasks:
`Tasks=addcontextmenufiles,addcontextmenufolders,associatewithfiles,addtopath`

Comment: Why is the tagged PowerShell? This is not a PowerShell issue.  This is a how do I auto-install VSCode silently question. The install process is the same as from cmd.exe, VBScript, or Powershell. All you are after is in the VSCode documentation. [As well as very clearly documented/shown in many blogs/articles, etc.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27vscode+silent+install%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment.
There are several pre-built scripts, in several GitHub Repos for silent installs:

[Example:](https://gist.github.com/EmmanuelTsouris/00bcaa9a3787a6451af5567f74b4e1c6)

```
#Install-VSCode

# Download URL, you may need to update this if it changes
$downloadUrl = "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=623230"

# What to name the file and where to put it
$installerFile = "vscode-install.exe"
$installerPath = (Join-Path $env:TEMP $installerFile)

# Install Options
# Reference:
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42582230/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-silently-without-auto-open-when-installation
# http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/
# I'm using /silent, use /verysilent for no UI

# Install with the context menu, file association, and add to path options (and don't run code after install: 
$installerArguments = "/silent /mergetasks='!runcode,addcontextmenufiles,addcontextmenufolders,associatewithfiles,addtopath'"

#Install with default options, and don't run code after install.
#$installerArguments = "/silent /mergetasks='!runcode'"

Write-Verbose "Downloading $installerFile..."
Invoke-Webrequest $downloadUrl -UseBasicParsing -OutFile $installerPath

Write-Verbose "Installing $installerPath..."
Start-Process $installerPath -ArgumentList $installerArguments -Wait

Write-Verbose "Cleanup the downloaded file."
Remove-Item $installerPath -Force
```

You can also automate installing VSCode extensions.

[Example:](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27code%20--install-extension%27&t=h_&ia=web&iai=r1-3&page=1&sexp=%7B%22biaexp%22%3A%22b%22%2C%22msvrtexp%22%3A%22b%22%2C%22mliexp%22%3A%22b%22%7D)

> Visual Studio Code: Getting Started with PowerShell
> https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35780.visual-studio-code-getting-started-with-powershell.aspx

```
code --install-extension ms-vscode.powershell
```

Comment: thank you,  I am going to have to come back and try this with the extensions.

Comment: No worries and happy scripting.